# How to start another activity while passing context of mainActivity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am starting other activity using intent from MainActivity.

Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProgramClass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now I want to access string.xml file in ProgramClass but `getResources()`, `getApplicationContext()`,`getContext()` are not able to get me that stringArray defined string.xml file.

As it generating an error, the possible solution I have is to create a constructor & pass context to ProgramClass from MainActivity().

but for doing that I need to create an object of ProgramClass in MainActivity while using an explicit Intent which takes .class parameter. How can I start an intent or another activity by passing context of MainActivity?

Comment: please update your `code` and `logcat` it sufficient detail for asking a question

Comment: post your ProgramClass  code

Comment: Any `Activity` or `Application` class **is** a `Context`. You don't need the MainActivity specifically, you just need a `Context`

Answer (score 2):

```
....

NewActivity.setParams(context);
Intent i = ..........
```

in NewActivity:

```
private static Context c;
public static void setParams(Context c){
    this.c = c;
}
```

This is a slight workaround because it uses static methods. This is however accessable from anywhere so any activity can change the context.

**ABOUT INTENT**

Intent is Android's native way to change from one activity to another. These do not change anything in the target/starting point class. They do however trigger the next step in the Activity Lifecycle:

[image]

There is no way to pass the context to the target activity using Intent. However, you can pass context, integers, booleans, strings, instances and so on using a static method as shown above. It works *as long as you **do not** alter the context* from the NewActivity class.

Also, I would like to add that all classes that extend Activity, Application, AppCompatActivity and so on are contexts. If you need to use context somewhere, you should pass it to a class without native context. If you are to use activities for main logic computing, try doing something that requires context and just write `this`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am starting other activity using intent from MainActivity. Here is my code:
>
> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProgramClass.class); 
> startActivity(intent);
> ```

Alright, that's great, but this won't work if `ProgramClass` doesn't extend some variant of `Activity`. And if it did, then you **should** have access to each of those methods you mentioned.

Comment: ProgramClass is extending AppCompatActivity. I think thats enough to call getResources() etc

Comment: It is, yes. So what's the problem? You should show a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

A **hack** would be that you define a static variable in your activity class and initialize it in onCreate method and later use that in your other class.

```
public static Context context = null;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
    }
```

and then in your other class use:

```
MainActivity.context.getResources().getString();
```